# Retrieve cluster centers / centroids from linkage matrix

Tags: scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

In scipy's hierarchical clustering one can build clusters starting from the linkage matrix Z. For instance,

```
fcluster(Z, 6,criterion='maxclust' )
```

would cut the dendrogram so that there will be 6 clusters in the end. Is there a way to get the coordinates of the center of each of those clusters? The position of the centers will differ depending on the metric and method used to build the dendrogram, but I would like to get the centers corresponding to the particular method that was used to build up Z.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical clustering does not use centers.

The centers may even be outside of the cluster.

Because of that, you will simply have to call `mean` yourself to compute centers, if you want centers.

Comment: I know there are no centers per se. What I am looking for is some sort of renormalization that keeps the original clusters. For instance, let's say I have the 6 clusters. I want to define a center for each, replace each cluster by their  respective centers and preserve the upper hierarchy when carrying out the clustering for these new centers. A simple mean would not do that.

Comment: This will likely not be possible in the original metric/dimensionality. But you can use the current distance matrix of the clustering algorithm at the desired height.

Comment: Is it `pdist` that does that?

Comment: No, pdist works in the original domain. I don't know if you get access to that matrix, you may need to modify the scipy source code. It is not commonly used. You'd rather use cophenetic distance.